# Subtract two metrics across a range and then find the average

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to subtract two metrics (guages) with the same lables over a time period [5m], and then average the result.

Queries I have tried,

```
avg_over_time(jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-dep-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"}[5m] -  jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"}[5m]) 

avg_over_time(jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-dep-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"} -  jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"})[5m]

avg_over_time((jvm_memory_bytes_max - on(area, app, kubernetes_pod_name) jvm_memory_bytes_used)[5m])
```

All of these have parse errors because the query is not correct.

Most of the example over ranges use **avg_over_time** to reduce a metric to a single value and then use an arithmetic operation.

I'm not sure if it's applicable because I don't want to average over a metric and then apply an arithmetic function. But rather, I want to apply the arithmetic operation on two data points of different metrics and then average the results.

Is that possible ? If so, how would I go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
avg_over_time((jvm_memory_bytes_max{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-dep-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"} -  jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap", app="ui",kubernetes_pod_name="ui-76b4f95bf4-xcs4s"})[5m:10s])
```

It calculates the difference of two metrics on every 10-second interval and then calculates the average over the differences for the last 5 minutes. The query uses [Prometheus subquery feature](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3).

Answer (score 1):

One way to have this working is to have the inner expression as a recording rule then apply `avg_over_time` to that for whatever range you like. As sub-queries are still very limited in PromQL using recording rules to create metrics from expressions to be used in other expressions is a common solution.

In you case it would be like:

```
...
  - name: memory_diff
    rules:
    - record: jvm_memory_diff_max_used
      expr: jvm_memory_bytes_max - jvm_memory_bytes_used
...
```

Then:

```
avg_over_time(jvm_memory_diff_max_used[5m])
```

Comment: Does adding recording rules impose load on the prometheus server ? 
Especially if there are multiple rules, would that scale ?